# What features does Firebug have that Safari 4's web inspector does not?

Tags: safari, webkit, firebug, web-inspector

I'm always hearing that Firebug is the best for web dev.  I prefer to use a webkit based browser, and I use Safari 4, or Webkit.  I don't mind the web inspector.

That's the background.  I'm wondering what features does firebug have that Safari 4 does not?

If it's compelling, sure i'll give it a shot, but i've been working with it today, dont see much difference.

Can someone enumerate, or point me to a place to enumerate the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [good article here](http://www.playingwithwire.com/tag/firebug/) which shows Safari 4's web inspector and in some places notes differences between Firebug and web inspector.

A big plus (at least for me) is that Firebug can be extended and there are some good extensions [here](http://getfirebug.com/extensions/) and [there](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I prefer Safari to Firefox, and I don't see any compelling reason to switch, based on these.

Comment: This answer doesn't really give the answer. The comparison is not very objective.